How to Integrate UPS OAuth 2.0 Authentication in a Legacy Codebase
I'm currently working on integrating UPS OAuth 2.0 authentication into an existing legacy codebase, and I'm facing some challenges. The legacy system is written in [vb.net] and has been functioning without modern authentication protocols until now.
UPSSecurity upss = new UPSSecurity();
UPSSecurityServiceAccessToken upssSvcAccessToken = new UPSSecurityServiceAccessToken();
upssSvcAccessToken.AccessLicenseNumber = CarrierConnection.AccessLicenseNumber;
upss.ServiceAccessToken = upssSvcAccessToken;
UPSSecurityUsernameToken upssUsrNameToken = new UPSSecurityUsernameToken();
upssUsrNameToken.Username = CarrierConnection.UserName;
upssUsrNameToken.Password = CarrierConnection.Password;
upss.UsernameToken = upssUsrNameToken;

var shpSvc = new ShipPortTypeClient(endpointConfiguration: ShipPortTypeClient.EndpointConfiguration.ShipPort, remoteAddress:CarrierConnection.url);
            


We cannot answer your question because we have no idea what your application is; what it does; nor why it needs to use UPS's OAuth2 library. Is this a desktop program? An old WebForms (.aspx) proejct? Access/VSTO? Something else?

It does shipment PICKUP & DELIVERY & SWAPPICKUP & SWAPDELIVERY
we received the communication that we have to migrate very soon below is the reference
https://developer.ups.com/api/reference

We know what UPS is - but I'm asking about the architecture of your application.

An old WebForms (.aspx) proejct

...and how/where do you intend to consume UPSSecurity? In a server-side Button_OnClick event - or in a Page_Load event - or in a background job task, or something else?

in a background job task

That seems straightforward then - so what actual problem are you facing?

I want to migrate these code to Auth 2.0 which Ups instructed
https://developer.ups.com/api/reference

...so the code you posted is not their new OAuth client lib, but their old one? If so, then that means you need to first pick an OAuth2 client library you want to use - or just use HttpClient with some simple extensions for client_credentials assuming you aren't interested in using refresh_token or a long-life'd access_token. I also assume this is strictly OAuth2 and not OIDC, so there's no id_token nor human-user flow involved?

yes it will be possible to implement in vb.net project give me some direction

Hello can you give me more insight?

I want to share with you the code button click code

how can i get latest WSDL file?
